# PHP called by Ajax in a page template cannot use Wordpress functions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, function

I have a page template in Wordpress that calls an ajax function. That ajax calls an php function in another file, all declared like mentioned in ajax api in Wordpress. Then I want to use in that php function a Wordpress function, like `get_template_dir_url()` and that call throw me an error that the `function get_template_dir_url() is not declared`.

I had tried to load `wp-load()` and other methods but they throws "already defined" errors. Your help with this would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `get_template_directory_uri()`, the problem is because you have a typo with the last character.

```
<?php
if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    echo get_template_directory_uri();
}
```

Comment: OMG!! Im such a d*ckhead .. you're totally right, I misspelled the function name. Thanks bro!!